# RavenDB query by index and DateTime

Tags: datetime, indexing, ravendb

I'm quite new to RavenDB so sorry if my question sounds stupid. I have a class which contains a DateTime property. I store instances of this class in RavenDB. I have defined index the following way:

```
from doc in docs.Orders
from docItemsItem in ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)doc.Items).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { Items_Price_Amount = docItemsItem.Price.Amount, Items_Quantity = docItemsItem.Quantity, Date = doc.Date }
```

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3055964/Capture.GIF <-- here's a screenshot

Here's class definition:

```
    public class Order
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public IList<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }

        public Order()
        {
            Items = new List<OrderItem>();
        }
    }
```

Now, when I try to query RavenDB with the index shown above, the query yields no result at all.

```
var orders = session.Query<Order>("OrdersIndex").Where(o => o.Date > DateTime.Now).ToList(); // orders.Count == 0
```

If I omit the index from query, like this:

```
var orders = session.Query<Order>().Where(o => o.Date > DateTime.Now).ToList(); // orders.Count == 128
```

a temporary index is created and eveything works as expected.

Does anyone has any idea what's wrong with my query?
Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Allright, I removed Fields Date, Items,Price,Amount and Items,Quantity via management studio (shown in screenshot), and now the query works fine. Anyone any idea why? What's the purpose to define those fields explicitly?

Comment: Can you try providing a full failing test to understand what is going on in here?

Comment: Thank you for your response Ayende, I appreciate your help and your effort you invested in RavenDB :) I will update my post in a few hours and upload the database and full working tests. But probably, this was my fault because I guess I wasn't using indexes correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Check that the date in the Index is stored as Index(x => x.Date, FieldIndexing.Default).

I had it set to FieldIndexing.Analysed, and wasn't getting the correct results back.

I need to read up more on the difference between the different FieldIndexing options :)